# ECS cluster cannot run tasks in private subnet when using EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a task definition that configured to use awsvpc network mode.
according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task_ec2.html):

> Only private subnets are supported for the awsvpc network mode.
>   Because tasks do not receive public IP addresses, a NAT gateway is
>   required for outbound internet access, and inbound internet traffic
>   should be routed through a load balancer.

I set up a NAT gateway in a public subnet(that has internet gateway) and config route table in the private subnet to send the traffic to NAT gateway. But when I want to create a task that resides in private subnet I get:

```
Run tasks failed Reasons : ["ATTRIBUTE"]. Learn more
```

If I choose the public subnet that the EC2 itself uses, It creates the task. But I cannot access the internet inside of my tasks.
My final goal is to get access to the internet from my tasks in the EC2.

UPDATE: My task definition:

```
{
"ipcMode": null,
"executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::783294628224:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
"containerDefinitions": [
{
"dnsSearchDomains": null,
"logConfiguration": {
"logDriver": "awslogs",
"options": {
"awslogs-group": "/ecs/TEST-Task-Definition",
"awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
"awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
}
},
"entryPoint": null,
"portMappings": [
{
"hostPort": 8500,
"protocol": "tcp",
"containerPort": 8500
},
{
"hostPort": 8501,
"protocol": "tcp",
"containerPort": 8501
}
],
"command": null,
"linuxParameters": null,
"cpu": 0,
"environment": [],
"resourceRequirements": null,
"ulimits": null,
"dnsServers": null,
"mountPoints": [],
"workingDirectory": null,
"secrets": null,
"dockerSecurityOptions": null,
"memory": null,
"memoryReservation": 500,
"volumesFrom": [],
"stopTimeout": null,
"image": "<MY ECR REPOSITORY ADDRESS FOR IMAGE 1>",
"startTimeout": null,
"dependsOn": null,
"disableNetworking": null,
"interactive": null,
"healthCheck": null,
"essential": true,
"links": null,
"hostname": null,
"extraHosts": null,
"pseudoTerminal": null,
"user": "root",
"readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
"dockerLabels": null,
"systemControls": null,
"privileged": true,
"name": "backend"
},
{
"dnsSearchDomains": null,
"logConfiguration": {
"logDriver": "awslogs",
"options": {
"awslogs-group": "/ecs/TEST-Task-Definition",
"awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
"awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
}
},
"entryPoint": null,
"portMappings": [
{
"hostPort": 80,
"protocol": "tcp",
"containerPort": 80
}
],
"command": null,
"linuxParameters": null,
"cpu": 0,
"environment": [],
"resourceRequirements": null,
"ulimits": null,
"dnsServers": null,
"mountPoints": [],
"workingDirectory": null,
"secrets": null,
"dockerSecurityOptions": null,
"memory": null,
"memoryReservation": 500,
"volumesFrom": [],
"stopTimeout": null,
"image": "<MY ECR REPOSITORY ADDRESS FOR IMAGE 2>",
"startTimeout": null,
"dependsOn": null,
"disableNetworking": null,
"interactive": null,
"healthCheck": null,
"essential": true,
"links": null,
"hostname": null,
"extraHosts": null,
"pseudoTerminal": null,
"user": "root",
"readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
"dockerLabels": null,
"systemControls": null,
"privileged": true,
"name": "frontend"
}
],
"memory": null,
"taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::783294628224:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
"family": "TEST-Task-Definition",
"pidMode": null,
"requiresCompatibilities": [
"EC2"
],
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"cpu": null,
"proxyConfiguration": null,
"volumes": [],
"placementConstraints": []
}
```

Comment: Do you use AWS ECS Optimized EC2 AMI ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html

Comment: @zdk yes. When I create cluster, it creates an EC2 with  appropriate AMI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeeded to fix my problem. As far as I know, when using `awsvpc` network mode in Task Definition, the tasks(or service) must create in the EC2 subnet. Additionally, if you want your tasks to have access to the internet, you should create a NAT gateway in another subnet which has a default route to Internet Gateway that resides in your VPC. In the task/service/EC2 subnet you have to add a default route to the NAT gateway. The only problem that occurs is that you cannot ssh to your EC2 anymore. If you want to ssh to your EC2, I think you should set up a Load Balancer.

Comment: If you want to SSH into your instances you should set up a bastion host in a public subnet and use it as a jump host to your instances. If you were SSHing through a Load Balancer, how would you control which instance are you SSHing into?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html

Make sure you have set agent parameter environment key `ECS_ENABLE_TASK_ENI` as `true`

Comment: I use the console to create the cluster. So it creates EC2 with appropriate AMI

Comment: Specificly the console creates the AMI with the id: amzn-ami-2018.03.o-amazon-ecs-optimized (ami-0d2f82a622136a696)

Comment: @MostafaFarzane Ok, great. Did you try the latest `20190301` image?

Comment: When I execute `docker image ls` it says: `amazon/amazon-ecs-agent   latest` and `amazon/amazon-ecs-pause   0.1.0 `

Comment: Also, please share your task definition because I think it contains a parameter that requires a specific container instance attribute that is not available on your container instances.