# ECS EC2 instance needs to be private and connect to ECS endpoint for container internet access

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575476/ecs-cluster-cannot-run-tasks-in-private-subnet-when-using-ec2), except the measures taken are not enough to solve my problem.

The aim is to run containers in ECS on EC2, which need to have internet access, but do not need incoming access.

My reading suggests that in order to launch containers in ECS on EC2 and still have internet access, the container must be run in a subnet where 0.0.0.0/0 is routed to a NAT gateway on a different subnet. I have set this up, and this works as expected, an EC2 instance in that subnet has access to the internet, and even if you give it a public IP address and add rules to the security group, you can't SSH to it from outside as there is no IGW for the subnet.

The problem is that the EC2 instance has to be in the same subnet as the containers. When launching the instance in a subnet that has no internet gateway, it can't connect to the ECS endpoint and so never registers in ECS (regardless of whether it has a public ip).

Changing the subnet to one with an internet gateway allows it to register to ECS, but then the containers either can't launch as they are in a different subnet, or if I use the same subnet as the host, they launch and have no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue was due to me trying to run the containers in `awsvpc` mode, which I was trying to do for cross compatibility with fargate mode.

So the workaround was to run the service and task in bridge mode, with the EC2 instance with a public IP and in a subnet with 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to an internet gateway.